# My audio visualizer doesn't work in chrome (but does in firefox)

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I have this audio visualizer (which I hope to get out of canvas and just use div blocks to achieve a better look). It works in firefox but when I run it in chrome I get this error message " Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" which was located at favicon.ico:1??? Not a clue what location means.

'''

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Music Station</title>
    
    <script src="http://cwilso.github.io/AudioContext-MonkeyPatch/AudioContextMonkeyPatch.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <audio id="player" controls>
       <source src="Music/Pink_Floyd/WishYouWereHere/ShineOnYouCrazyDiamond(PartsI-V).mp3">
   </audio>
  
   <canvas width="500px" height="400px" background-color="#000000" id="soundCanv"></canvas>
   
   
   
    <script>
        
        window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext||window.webkitAudioContext;
        let audioCtx = new AudioContext();
      var music=document.getElementById("player");  
     var canvas=document.getElementById("soundCanv");
        var canvasCtx=canvas.getContext("2d");
        var myAudio=document.querySelector('audio');
        
        
var analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser(); 
//    var source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(music.captureStream());
            var source=audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(myAudio);
source.connect(analyser);
        analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination);

console.log("Hello");
    
    
    analyser.fftSize = 256;
var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
console.log(bufferLength);
var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

console.log("Hello There");
    
        function draw() {
            
      canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0,canvas.width, canvas.height);

      analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);

      canvasCtx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
      canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            
            var barWidth = (canvas.width / bufferLength) * 2.5;
var barHeight;
var x = 0;
            
                  for(var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
        barHeight = dataArray[i]/2;

        canvasCtx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + (barHeight+100) + ',50,50)';
        canvasCtx.fillRect(x,canvas.height-barHeight/2,barWidth,barHeight);

        x += barWidth + 1;
      }
        window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);    
    };
        window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        draw();
    
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

'''

Is there a way to get this to work in chrome? its 2020 web audio api should have been smoothed over by now.

Comment: The `favicon.ico` error has nothing to do with it.

Comment: ok, this also shows up MusicPlayer.html:21 The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page. This shows up at top of console log. Does this require mouse event or would it work to just use an if statement with the boolean of '''music.play''''?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome requires that `AudioContext`s must be created only from code run because of an user event. You can solve this by wrapping your code inside a `click` event handler or something similar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Music Station</title>
    
    <script src="http://cwilso.github.io/AudioContext-MonkeyPatch/AudioContextMonkeyPatch.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <audio id="player" controls>
       <source src="Music/Pink_Floyd/WishYouWereHere/ShineOnYouCrazyDiamond(PartsI-V).mp3">
   </audio>
  
   <canvas width="500px" height="400px" background-color="#000000" id="soundCanv"></canvas>
   <button id="start-btn">Start</button>
   
   
    <script>

      document.getElementById("start-btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
        
        window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext||window.webkitAudioContext;
        let audioCtx = new AudioContext();
      var music=document.getElementById("player");  
     var canvas=document.getElementById("soundCanv");
        var canvasCtx=canvas.getContext("2d");
        var myAudio=document.querySelector('audio');
        
        
var analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser(); 
//    var source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(music.captureStream());
            var source=audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(myAudio);
source.connect(analyser);
        analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination);

console.log("Hello");
    
    
    analyser.fftSize = 256;
var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
console.log(bufferLength);
var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

console.log("Hello There");
    
        function draw() {
            
      canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0,canvas.width, canvas.height);

      analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);

      canvasCtx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
      canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            
            var barWidth = (canvas.width / bufferLength) * 2.5;
var barHeight;
var x = 0;
            
                  for(var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
        barHeight = dataArray[i]/2;

        canvasCtx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + (barHeight+100) + ',50,50)';
        canvasCtx.fillRect(x,canvas.height-barHeight/2,barWidth,barHeight);

        x += barWidth + 1;
      }
        window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);    
    };
        window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        draw();
    
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```